# ctrl+, not working in mono develop

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop, shortcut

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> should be the search shortcut in mono develop, right? It did work yesterday but don't work today. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  work usually as search within the activated c# script. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the key binding is properly set in `Options > Preferences > Key Bindings`.